# how create frontend and backend structure for modules in yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

The structure im looking for is like:

```
modulesName
   frontend
     controllers
     models
     views
     web

   backend
     controllers
     models
     views
     web
```

is that possible ?
we should use basic or advance ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But if you need this kind of structure it is good to use Yii2-advanced template. Or if you want you can use also starter kit by trntv here is [link](https://github.com/yii2-starter-kit/yii2-starter-kit). It has lots of features that will easy your development.

What if you want it as module, you need basic template but you will not have separate web folders. Just use Gii to create module. Instructions how to work and create modules are given [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-modules).

Comment: Thats ok but i need to achieve that structure